# How can I access camunda modeler in a docker container?

Tags: dockerfile, camunda-modeler

I need to access camunda modeler (desktop version) inside a container. The platform image provided by camunda on docker hub doesnt have the modeler.

I tried creating an image of the desktop camunda modeler but it didnt build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running GUI applications in a container is rather uncommon. I would explore the alternatives below. However, if you are absolutely determined that this is what you need to do, I would look at articles like https://www.howtogeek.com/devops/how-to-run-gui-applications-in-a-docker-container/.

- Camunda 8.1 self managed modeler beta (for another 2 month enterprise only) is availbe as docker compose https://docs.camunda.io/docs/next/self-managed/modeler/web-modeler/installation/
- Camunda 8.2 self managed modeler (to be released second Tue of April)
- Camunda SaaS free trial or professional tier https://accounts.cloud.camunda.io/signup
- use bpmni.io online or embedded in your own application https://demo.bpmn.io/

Hope one of those options does the trick for you.